# Success block is reached but Response Object is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, get, afnetworking

I'm having an issue using AFNetworking Get method to call my server.
I'm using this method in a manager, class is declare as follow :

```
    #import "AGZClient.h"
#import "AGZServiceModel.h"

// Constants used for every webservice call
static NSString * const agendizeApiKey = @"privateApiKey";
static NSString * const agendizeURLString = AGENDIZE_API_URL;

@implementation AGZClient

+ (AGZClient *)sharedAGZClient
{
    static AGZClient *_sharedAGZClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedAGZClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:agendizeURLString]];
    });

    return _sharedAGZClient;
}

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if (self) {
        self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        //[self.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:100.0];
        self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", @"application/json", nil];
    }

    return self;
}
    // Get all the appointments for a company and a staff
- (void)getAppointmentsForCompany:(int)companyID andStaff:(int)staffID
{
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    parameters[@"apiKey"] = agendizeApiKey;
    parameters[@"token"] = @"privateToken";

    [self GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"companies/%d/appointments?staffId=%d", companyID, staffID] parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(AGZClient:successedReceiveAppointmentsForStaffList:)]) {
            [self.delegate AGZClient:self successedReceiveAppointmentsForStaffList:responseObject];
        }
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(AGZClient:failedReceiveAppointmentsForStaffList:)]) {
            [self.delegate AGZClient:self failedReceiveAppointmentsForStaffList:error];
        }
    }];
}
```

The success block is reached but it seems that when my datas are too big, it doesn't wait for the datas, hence my responseObject in the successBlock is nil

I have no idea how to solve this, how come the success block is not called only when all the datas has arrived?
What should i do here to solve this, help please!

Comment: Is it JSON format you expect in response ? Did you set proper request/response encoders? What is the class you pasted, since you are using [self GET] method, please provide a code for that as well

Comment: Thanks for helping @GrzegorzKrukowski, I edited my post so you can see all informations about my class

Comment: Ok - and server side is responding with JSON or plain text or what kind of format you are using ?